# TextMate Scala bundle

Tags: macos, textmate, scala

Scala and Textmate have been around for a while, but I wonder why there's no [TM Scala Bundle here yet](http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Bundles/).

Is there a usable one without a hard/uncommon installation process?

The one which is as easy as other common bundles, usually clone or checkout the bundle to the appropriate directory then just osascript reload and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install the [GetBundles](http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Review/Bundles/GetBundles.tmbundle/) (plural) and run it. I see 7 Scala bundles listed. You will have to install each bundle to see what they do.

Also I just noticed there is a [Scala.tmbundle](http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Review/Bundles/Scala.tmbundle/) in "Review".